# karate-config.js params not accessible inside the feature file being called by another feature file

Tags: karate

Feature file 1 is called scenario in feature file 2.

I am printing baseUrl param in file 1 and file 2. In file 1 the baseUrl is printed but not getting printed in file 2.

File 2:

```
@ignore
Feature: Scenario related api-calls
  Background:
    * print baseUrl
    * url baseUrl

  @create_scenario
  Scenario: create_scenario
```

File 1:

```
Feature: Handling a Scenario
  Background:
    * print baseUrl
    * def create_scenario_data = callonce create_scenario_function default_create_scenario_data
    * def scenarioDetail = create_scenario_data.response
```

EDIT 1:

```
@ignore
Feature: Direct function definitions for east access

  Scenario:
    * def create_scenario_function = function(data) { return     karate.call("classpath:karate/utils/api_caller/scenario.feature@create_scenario", {requestBody: data, baseUrl: baseUrl})}
```

Comment: sorry please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: After a lot of debugging found this: if we call a feature file from js then karate-config params are not accessible inside this

Comment: that doesn't sound right to me. see if you can replicate and submit an issue